# Add a User to AWS Identity Pool Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Update: 
I am trying to add a user to my identity pool. I keep getting this error message:

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 8.)
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}
```

This code is in my `App Delegate` at launch:

```
//sets up dynamo db   
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId) 
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

And then in my main `ViewController`:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
    if (task.error != nil){
        print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
        print(task.error!)
    }
    else {
        // the task result will contain the identity id
        let cognitoId = task.result!
        print("Cognito id: \(cognitoId)")
    }
    return task;
})
```

I know that when that code is run, that a user has successfully signed in. Similar code can be found on this [page](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html).

Update 2:

It seemed like duplicate code in my `AppDelegate` to set `AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration`twice, which according to [this](https://medium.com/@dkabyshev/api-less-backend-for-ios-with-aws-in-swift-part-1-cf230f080af5) source gets ignored the second time 
which may be why I am getting a null error. When that code is called again the credential provider is null (maybe). So If I comment out those three lines in my `AppDelegate`, I get a new error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.service.cognitoidentity.AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper Code=0 "Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Obtaining an identity id in another thread failed or didn't complete within 5 seconds.})
```

I'm not sure where else I could be calling for an id. Especially if I removed the code from the `AppDelegate`, any help is greatly appreciated!

A bit about the Identity Pool: 
I don't want any access that is not authenticated, so when I set it up in the console those are the settings I chose. And I have triple checked to make sure that all the `AppId`, `AppSecrets`, etc have been correctly copied over.

Comment: I can add other variables that I have access to if that is useful